# calling ruby instance method

Tags: ruby, instance, instance-variables, instance-methods

```
class R
  def initialize(number)
    @number = number
  end

  attr_accessor :number
end

r = R.new(3)

r.number => 3
r.@number => syntax error
r.(@number) => undefined method call
```

Why can't the instance variable invoked this way?

As far as I know thanks to the attr_accessor

```
def number
  @number
end
```

So
   `r.number` method should return `self.@number` which is `r.@number`

What did I miss?

Comment: here sawa answer is perfect one way you can get the instance variable `@number` value `r.instance_variable_get(:@number)` by this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `r.number` method should return `self.@number` which is `r.@number`

No. Nowhere in the definition of the `number` method says `self.@number`. It says: `@number`. It should return the value of `@number`.

`@number` is an instance variable, not a method. You cannot call it (like that or in any other way), you can only refer to it from an appropriate scope.

Comment: Is there any other conventional way to get into the scope besides the getter method?

Comment: @SzilardMagyar `instance_eval`. But that defeats OOP, and is also slow. If you can use a different syntax, you can use `instance_variable_get`, as Rajarshi Das notes.